# ActiveAdmin skipping action_item with next versus proc

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

There are two ways of skipping an item in ActiveAdmin gem

```
  action_item :user_reviewed, only: %i[show] do
    next unless resource.individual?
    ....
  end
```

vs documented one:

```
  action_item :user_reviewed, only: %i[show], if: proc{ resource.individual? } do
    ....
  end
```

both, proc and next would skip creating the action_item and move to next one, but from the technical point of view (not that documentation says so), which one would perform better and more important is - why?
In my understanding next is faster since it's just skips to the next element, compared to proc that means calling a function.

Comment: The next will probably be faster but truthfully the difference will be so minuscule you really won't notice it. They're both called after the resource is instantiated.

Comment: @JoshBrody is makes sense of course, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proc, you can delay execution to render time. If the condition to show the action_item would depend on data from the request cycle (a get parameter, a session cookie, a logged in admin_user, or perhaps an active scope in an index page), you can use proc.

This will cause an error at server start:

```
action_item :user_reviewed, only: %i[show], if: params[:scope] == 'somescopename'
```

Activeadmin registers the resource at server start time, and no request-cycle data is present.  When needed you can use:

```
action_item :user_reviewed, only: %i[show], if: proc {params[:scope] == 'somescopename' }.
```

This is also is helpful for collection filters. Sometimes they need to be filled with data at render time, not at rails server startup time. Check https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html and search for `proc`.